# Tableau - how do I search for a term across all columns where the column names are undetermined?

Tags: etl, tableau-api, data-analysis

I need to be able to use Tableau to search for a term e.g. "xyz123" across all the columns within multiple Excel files where the names and numbers of the columns aren't fixed, so it just has to dynamically filter on whatever is in the Excel file.

Does Tableau have a function that could do this?

Comment: No. You're better off using python. Use pandas, loop over all the files into dataframes then search.

Comment: @Bernardo unfortunately I don't have the option of using Python in this scenario (work).